# TYPO3: Can I delete the typo3_src-version folder

Tags: typo3, version, directory

Just a small thing I noticed, when upgrading the typo3 version trough the installation tool a new folder will be created for the new typo3 version.

In the root folder of my Typo3 installation I have following three folders + all the default files/folders:

```
typo3_src-8.7.8
typo3_src-8.7.13
typo3_src-8.7.15
```

Now my question is, is it safe to delete the first two folders for me, or are there necessary files in there?

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Deleting older version folder is fine. it's not effect your typo3 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting folders of older versions is perfectly fine.

Comment: Because the installer does not delete them, in case you need to go back to an older version quickly (rollback).